# Google Analytics can't trackEvent in a function

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have a basic asynchronous Google Analytics code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function(){ 
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
})();
```

Than lower, I listen for a click and want to track it with Analytics:

```
$('#content').on("click", "#btn", function(e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    this.form.target = '_self';
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', elem.text()]);
    return true;
});
```

The click is fired, I can see that _gaq is defined
But somehow, the event never get tracked?
I read https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=fr 
and differents Stack Overflow answers, 
but I don't found what I'm missing...
All the examples I found, put the code directly on the element with OnClick. Is that mandatory or can I put the code in a function just like I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_trackEvent` records data by requesting a tracking pixel from Google Analytics servers, with the data as parameters on the request.  If the browser starts processing a new page (because of following a link, or submitting a form), then the image request can be canceled, and the data not recorded.

Google's beta Universal Analytics (analytics.js) allows the use of a `hitCallback` function that's executed when the data has been sent.

The usual pattern with ga.js is to add a slight delay (150ms) before following the link or submitting a form.

Try something like

```
$('#content').on("click", "#btn", function(e) {
  var elem = $(this);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', elem.text()]);
  var form = this.form;
  form.target = '_self';
  setTimeout(function(){ form.submit(); }, 150);
  e.preventDefault();
```

});

Comment: Thx and congrats on your 4k!